# SEO URL's difference / and /index.php

Tags: url, optimization, seo, sem

I have a question about SEO. Are this two different URL's:

```
http://www.domainroot.org/
```

and

```
http://www.domainroot.org/index.php
```

Thankyou

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are two different URLs. They may both access the same resource, but they are different URLs.

This can cause SEO issues as this would result in duplicate content. In this case conical URLs or doing a 301 redirect from one to the other would solve this issue.